# Delete a cookie after it expires in angular using $cookies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I'm trying to authenticate an user via cross-origin-resource-sharing.

I've set an `auth_token` as my cookie like this:

`$cookies.put('auth_token', res.data.token, {'expires': res.data.tokenExpires});`

to be able to authenticate the user and also added an expiration timer which is around 4 hours.

After the token expires it doesn't remove itself like I thought it would.

How can I then check and remove the cookie manually if it has expired.

Comment: Have you checked if you put the correct date format in the expires fields ? Because $cookie work with a specific format : 'Wdy, DD Mon YYYY HH:MM:SS GMT' ?

Comment: hi @NotBad4U http://i.imgur.com/Cg1b7EU.png that's how it's being stored